# Create a Contact in Microsoft Bookings Failing

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I'm using the Microsoft Graph REST Beta API call:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/{id}/customers
```

With body payload:

```
{
    "displayName": "User Name",
    "emailAddress": "email%40eventhorizon.llc"
}
```

I get a 201 response (success). But the data in Bookings is corrupted when I look at the interface, and so is the JSON response, which has a blank email, etc. although I sent this data to the API.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

JSON Response (note that it picks up the email address in the ODATA):

```
{
'@odata.context':'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#bookingBusinesses('email%40eventhorizon.llc')/customers/$entity',
       'id':'ee6004dd-c4af-435d-b3a9-532b2753753e',
       'displayName':'ee6004dd-c4af-435d-b3a9-532b2753753e',
       'emailAddress':null
}
```

Java Code:

```
        IAuthenticationResult auth = msft.getAuth();
        String accessToken = auth.accessToken();
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST") || method.equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")) {
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            String str = payload.toString();
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(str.getBytes());
            out.flush();
        }

        httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```